# Roulette Again Chances to Walk away with at least $1010

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, gambling

You go to Las Vegas with $\$1000$ and play roulette $100$ times by betting $\$10$ on the number 36
each time. Compute the probability of leaving the Casino with at least $\$1010$. Hint: Each bet
you have chance $1/38$ of winning $\$350$ and chance $37/38$ of loosing $\$10$.

So in order to have at least $\$1010$ when you leave you have to win at least $3$ times.  $$3\cdot 1050+1000=2050-(97\cdot 10)=1080$$
I am assuming that I am looking for the probability of $97$ losses or less.
I interpreted this as a Binomial Distribution, which I plugged into Excel with the following calculation:
`=Binom.dist(97,100,(37/38),TRUE)`, however, it does not get me the right answer.  I am unsure on how to fix the program.

Thank you!

Comment: `=BINOM.DIST(E7,100,(37/38),TRUE)` came out to $0.491567$ when I tried it. What makes you think this is not the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what casino you've been going to but on standard Roulette there are $37$ numbers, numbered $0-36$.  So I doubt it's a maths error.

By your method, plugging

```
=Binom.dist(97,100,(36/37),TRUE)
```

into Excel gives $\approxeq0.5093$

Well, anybody knows your expected winnings from any casino bet are less than what you took in so the answer must be $\approxeq1-0.5093=0.4907$

Comment: American Roulette also has $00$ to make $38$ numbers altogether.

Comment: Negative expected value does not imply that the chance of winning is less than $\frac12.$ Consider the simple example of a bet where you roll one six-sided fair die, lose $\$10$ if you roll $1,$ and otherwise win $\$1.$

Comment: @DavidK on your first point, thanks. I didn't know that.  Until OP replies I guess we won't know which roulette wheel they're working with.  On your 2nd point, good point I'm making a leap of intuition due to the relatively large sample size.

Comment: It's an interesting phenomenon. If you only bet once then you have a small chance of a large win and a large chance of a small win. But if you bet $35$ times you have a better than $60\%$ chance to win at least once (on either a $37$- or $38$-number wheel), and one win is enough to more than offset the losses. The *expected* winnings are still negative, of course. At $36$ bets you need two wins to get ahead and the chance of doing so is a lot less. But there are still some longer strings of bets where the chance to come out at least slightly ahead is greater than $50\%.$

Comment: A little spreadsheeting confirms that if your strategy is to place a sequence of $396$ or more bets you have less than a $50\%$ chance to have a net win at the end, even with only $37$ numbers on the wheel. With $38$ numbers any sequence of $180$ or more bets has less than a $50\%$ chance to have a net win. So that's where the large-sample effect becomes overwhelming.

Comment: @DavidK I was aware of it. If you set a game (stake $\$1000$) up such that you have $49\%$ chance of coming away with $\$1$ and $51\%$ chance of coming out with $\$1001$ then you're more likely to come away a winner than not, but expected value of winnings are very negative. I had obliviously waved it away because of the relatively large number of samples.